# What does $U \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Ok so I get the basics of this, I just can't put it all together. $U$ is contained in the cartesian product of $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R$. What is $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R$ though? I know what a cartesian product is, but this seems weird to me. Someone please help explain this part, thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R = \{ (a,b) \mid a \in \mathbb R^n, b \in \mathbb R \}$.

Comment: $\in\ne\subset!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could understand it as space-time which $R^n$ is space dimension and the other $R$ is for time. In this view, $U=\{(x,t)\}$ contains points representing an event occuring at point $x$ and time $t$. Does it help?

Comment: great example, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R$ is the set of all pairs
whose first component comes from the set $\mathbb R^n$ and the second component comes from the set $\mathbb R$.
So
$$U = (\mathbf v, x)$$
with $\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^n$ and $x\in \mathbb R$.

Since $\mathbb R^n$ is the set of all $n$-tuples over $\mathbb R$, the $n$-tuple $\mathbf v$ has the form $\mathbf v = (v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$. So $U$ can also be written down as
$$
U = ((v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n),x)
$$
with $v_1,v_2,\ldots,x\in\mathbb R$.
This is occasionally abbreviated as
$$
U = (v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n;x)
$$
or even
$$
U = (v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n,x).
$$